# How to do user registration and authentication in PHP with ArangoDB?

Tags: php, database, nosql, arangodb, arangodb-php

ArangoDB is a flexible multi-model database server which has very nice features and lots of good documentation. It's a young, very promising open source project with a growing community but not many real world examples to get started.

A common real-world example, is user registration and authentication. It's needed in most applications out there.

So, how to do user registration and authentication in PHP with ArangoDB?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can run the following example code directly and it will run through a user registration and authentication by providing some fictional user data.
It will display each step that it's doing. From collection-creation, to user-registration, authentication and finally cleaning up the collection again.
There are also lots of comments that explain what is being done, in order to make it easier to understand.

Just put this code in a file, configure the path to autoload.php according to your environment and visit its link with a browser.
This code requires [ArangoDB 1.2 and up](http://www.arangodb.org/)  as well as the [ArangoDB-PHP client version 1.2](https://github.com/triAGENS/ArangoDB-PHP/tree/1.2) and up.
It expects ArangoDB to be running on localhost and listening on port 8529.

**Note1**: The script automatically creates the 'users' collection and a unique skip-list index on 'username'. It also will drop the collection in the end.
       If you want to create the collection by hand instead of automatically, you need to comment out the parts where the collection and index are created as well as the part where the collection is dropped.
After that open up a shell to ArangoDB (arangosh) and run the following commands in it:

```
arangosh> db._createDocumentCollection('users');
arangosh> db.users.ensureUniqueSkiplist("username");
```

if you want to drop the collection, type:

```
arangosh> db.users.drop();
```

**Note2**: I have intentionally avoided introducing more OO style, like user objects, address objects, etc.. in order to keep it simple.

So, finally here's the script.

```
<?php

namespace triagens\ArangoDb;


// use this and change it to the path to autoload.php of the arangodb-php client if you're using the client standalone...
// require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/triagens/ArangoDb/autoload.php';

// ...or use this and change it to the path to autoload.php in the vendor directory if you're using Composer/Packagist
require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';


// This function will provide us with our pre-configured connection options. 
function getConnectionOptions()
{
    $traceFunc = function ($type, $data) {
        print "TRACE FOR " . $type . PHP_EOL;
    };

    return array(
        ConnectionOptions::OPTION_ENDPOINT      => 'tcp://localhost:8529/',
        // endpoint to connect to
        ConnectionOptions::OPTION_CONNECTION    => 'Close',
        // can use either 'Close' (one-time connections) or 'Keep-Alive' (re-used connections)
        ConnectionOptions::OPTION_AUTH_TYPE     => 'Basic',
        // use basic authorization
        /*
        ConnectionOptions::OPTION_AUTH_USER       => '',                      // user for basic authorization
        ConnectionOptions::OPTION_AUTH_PASSWD     => '',                      // password for basic authorization
        ConnectionOptions::OPTION_PORT            => 8529,                    // port to connect to (deprecated, should use endpoint instead)
        ConnectionOptions::OPTION_HOST            => "localhost",             // host to connect to (deprecated, should use endpoint instead)
        */
        ConnectionOptions::OPTION_TIMEOUT       => 5,
        // timeout in seconds
        //ConnectionOptions::OPTION_TRACE           => $traceFunc,              // tracer function, can be used for debugging
        ConnectionOptions::OPTION_CREATE        => false,
        // do not create unknown collections automatically
        ConnectionOptions::OPTION_UPDATE_POLICY => UpdatePolicy::LAST,
        // last update wins
    );
}


// This function tries to persist the user data into the database upon registration
// it will fail if a user with the same username already exists.
function register($connection, $username, $password, $registrationData)
{
    // This would be where you call the function that encrypts your password like you did for storage earlier
    $hashedPassword = md5($password);

    // assign the collection to a var (or type it directly into the methods parameters)
    $collectionId = 'users';

    //create an example document or an array in order to pass to the following byExample method
    $document = Document::createFromArray(
        array('username' => $username, 'password' => $hashedPassword, 'data' => $registrationData)
    );

    // Get an instance of the collection handler
    $documentHandler = new DocumentHandler($connection);

    try {
        // query the given $collectionId by example using the previously declared $exampleDocument array
        $result = $documentHandler->add($collectionId, $document);

        // return the result;
        return $result;
    } catch (Exception $e) {

        if ($e->getCode()) {
            echo ('User already exists... ');
        } else {
            // any other error
            echo ('An error occured. Exception: ' . $e);
        }
    }
}


// This function tries to authenticate the user and will return an array with its data
function authenticate($connection, $username, $password)
{
    // This would be where you call the function that encrypts your password like you did for storage earlier
    $hashedPassword = md5($password);

    // assign the collection to a var (or type it directly into the methods parameters)
    $collectionId = 'users';

    //create an example document or an array in order to pass to the following byExample method
    $exampleDocumentArray = array('username' => $username, 'password' => $hashedPassword);

    // Get an instance of the collection handler
    $documentHandler = new CollectionHandler($connection);

    try {
        // query the given $collectionId by example using the previously declared $exampleDocument array
        $cursor = $documentHandler->byExample($collectionId, $exampleDocumentArray);
        // check if the count of the cursor is one or not.
        if ($cursor->getCount() == 1) {
            // do some fancy login stuff here...

            // get the current document from the cursor
            $userDocument = $cursor->current();

            // set session uid to the document key that was set automatically by ArangoDB,
            // since we didn't provide our own on registration
            $_SESSION['uid'] = $userDocument->getKey();

            // extract and return the document in form of an array
            return $userDocument->getAll();
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo ('An error occured. Exception: ' . $e . '<br>');
    }
}


// register the connection to ArangoDB
$connection = new Connection(getConnectionOptions());


// register a collection handler to work with the 'users' collection
$collectionHandler = new CollectionHandler($connection);


// create the 'users' collection...
// remark those lines if you want to create the collection by hand.
echo "creating 'users' collection...";
try {
    $collection = new Collection();
    $collection->setName('users');
    $collectionHandler->create($collection);
    echo "created.<br>";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo ('Could not create collection. Exception: ' . $e . '<br>');
}


// create unique skip list index in 'users' collection on field ''username'...
// remark those lines if you want to create the index by hand.
echo "creating unique skip list index in 'users' collection on field ''username'... ";
try {
    $collection = new Collection();
    $collection->setName('users');
    $collectionHandler->index('users', 'skiplist', array('username'), true);
    echo "created.<br>";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo ('Could not create skip list index. Exception: ' . $e . '<br>');
}


// let's assume those variables hold your username / password
$userNameProvided = 'jane';
$passwordProvided = 'mysecretpassword';

// here we pass some structured registration data
$registrationData = array(
    'name'      => 'Jane',
    'surname'   => 'Doe',
    'addresses' => array(
        'email' => array('jane@doe.com', 'jane2@doe.com'),
        'home'  => array(
            array('street' => 'Brooklyn Ave.', 'number' => 10),
            array('street' => '54th Street', 'number' => 340, 'is_primary' => true)
        )
    )
);

// First register
echo "trying to register user for the first time... ";
$result = register($connection, $userNameProvided, $passwordProvided, $registrationData);
if ($result) {
    echo " " . $userNameProvided . " registered<br>";
} else {
    echo "failed<br>";
}


// Trying to register user with same username a second time
echo "trying to register user with same username a second time... ";
$result = register($connection, $userNameProvided, $passwordProvided, $registrationData);
if ($result) {
    echo "registered<br>";
} else {
    echo "failed<br>";
}


// now authenticate with the correct username/password combination
echo "trying to authenticate with the correct username/password combination... ";
if ($userArray = authenticate($connection, $userNameProvided, $passwordProvided)) {
    echo "login successful. ";
    echo '<br>';
    // do some fancy after-login stuff here...
    echo "<br>Welcome back " . $userArray['username'] . '!<br>';
    if (count($userArray['data']['addresses']['email']) > 0) {
        echo "Your primary mail address is " . $userArray['data']['addresses']['email'][0] . '<br>';
    }
    foreach ($userArray['data']['addresses']['home'] as $key => $value) {
        if (array_key_exists('is_primary', $value)) {
            $homeAddress = $userArray['data']['addresses']['home'][$key];
            echo "Your primary home address is " . $homeAddress['number'] . ', ' . $homeAddress['street'] . '<br>';
            // if found, break out of the loop. There can be only one... primary address!
            break;
        }
    }
} else {
    // re-display login form. +1 the wrong-login counter...
    echo "wrong username or password<br>";
}
echo '<br>';

// now authenticate with the wrong username/password combination
echo "trying to authenticate with the wrong username/password combination... ";
if (authenticate($connection, $userNameProvided, 'I am a wrong password')) {
    // do some fancy after-login stuff here...
    echo "login successful<br>";
} else {
    // re-display login form. +1 the wrong-login counter...
    echo "wrong username or password<br>";
}


// truncate the collection... not needed if dropping, but only here to empty the collection of its tests
// in case you decide to not create and drop the collection through this script, but by hand.
echo "truncating collection...";
try {
    $collectionHandler->truncate('users');
    echo "truncated.<br>";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die ('Could not truncate collection. Exception: ' . $e . '<br>');
}


// finally drop the collection...
// remark those lines if you want to drop the collection by hand.
echo "dropping collection...";
try {
    $collectionHandler->drop('users');
    echo "dropped.<br>";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    die ('Could not drop collection. Exception: ' . $e . '<br>');
}
```